# How to get all email templates are using - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

i want to know which email templates are using on my store

I thought a way find on core_config_data, path like email, and can check value - But it's not best way i think

Because some modules don't use email config for their module

Can some one help me, thanks

Comment: which email you want to check like order, invoice etc?

Comment: I want all email, include email on custom module